# Changing views from method in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using a commandButton from primefaces 3.5 like this:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-note"
         action="/public/page2.jsf?faces-redirect=true"
         actionListener="#{managebean.myMethod}"
         update="@form :growl">
    <f:attribute name="idTest" value="#{testBean.idTest}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

but the the manage view is `@viewscope`, that's why i'm using `f:attribute`, but with that button, the method executes first(loading info in some beans, with the idTest), and then changes the view, which (because of the scope) resets all my beans.

Any way to work around this? maybe making the page change and then executing the method? (and how can i do that, because that would be awesome)

Comment: Do you want to execute a method after redirecting to `page2.jsf`...?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `preRenderView` Listener on `page2.jsf`, which will get called once navigate away from `page1` and before Rendering the `page2`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <f:event listener="#{managebean.myMethod}" type="preRenderView" />

    <h:body>
          <h1>JSF Page2</h1>
        </h:body>
</html>
```

**Important:** `preRenderView` event will be fired for all AJAX calls in `page2.jsf`, regardless of if its a First request or subsequent request, check for post-back requests using `FacesContext.isPostback()`.

```
public void myMethod() {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        /* Your Code */
    }
}
```